# Covert GMT time to local time zone - issues

Tags: android

I am trying to convert GMT time to local device time zone.But the GMT time

```
    String res;
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    String strTimeZone = tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);

    SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mma");
    sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    SimpleDateFormat sdfmad = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mma");
    sdfmad.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(strTimeZone));

    String inpt = "09:00am";
    Date inptdate = null;
    try {
        inptdate = sdfgmt.parse(inpt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("GMT:\t\t" + sdfgmt.format(inptdate));
    System.out.println("Current Time:\t" + sdfmad.format(inptdate));
    res = sdfmad.format(inptdate);
```

GMT time returns as 00:00am.I cant convert the 9:00am gmt time to local device time zone(GMT+5:30)

Comment: hi try this may be help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725246/java-android-convert-a-gmt-time-string-to-local-time

Comment: The code looks ok. Is this really the code that causes your issues? Consider debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String inpt = "09:00amZ";
Date date = null;
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mmaX").parse(inpt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mma");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Be sure to add a "Z" at the end of the input to tell that this time is in GMT time zone.

If you need a default to the device time zone instead of hardcode replace the `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));` 
by `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`